# facebook Graph API post to wall doesn't accept new line

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am developing a small application for facebook.
In my application I post content to a fan page's wall.

When the user enters a new line character the post completely ignores it. How can I solve this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Facebook Graph API Linebreak](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/7126974/facebook-graph-api-linebreak)

Comment: it seems every time someone finds a way, it gets closed by facebook.

Comment: yes, very annoying. There are several of facebook's support team here on stackoverflow. Is there any way to contact them directly?

Comment: this is the best place to contact them directly: http://www.facebook.com/groups/fbdevelopers/

Comment: Thank you, I've got a feeling this is going to prove very valuable :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IF you send the following text

hello%0Aline+2

The posted message will look like

*hello*
*line 2*

Checked it right now:)

Answer (score 1):

this work fine for me:

```
// first: replace normal \n (or "\\n") for "\r\n"
$mensaje=str_replace("\\n","\r\n",$reg['mensaje']);

// second: this only is for clear special characters
$mensaje=utf8_encode($mensaje);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `html_entities`, otherwise the POST request is not transferred properly.

Comment: Maybe `preg_replace` new lines?

Answer (score 0):

use \r\n without any spaces in facebook graph api then you will get line break